# SQL: how to concatenate results against a single user?

Tags: sql

```
username      Name                    Skills
zainniazi     Zain Khan NiaZi         C
zainniazi     Zain Khan NiaZi         C++
```

How to get result in a single line where skills are concatenated? Like:

```
username      Name                    Skills
zainniazi     Zain Khan NiaZi         C,C++
```

Comment: Using which RDBMS? MySQL?

Comment: Please provide a schema of the database and a query that you've tried.

Comment: Have a look at this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/451415/simulating-group-concat-mysql-function-in-microsoft-sql-server-2005

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

**SQL SERVER**

```
SELECT
      T1.username
    , T1.Name
    , Skills = STUFF((
          SELECT ',' + T2.Skills
          FROM TableName T2
          WHERE T1.username = T2.username
          FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 1, '')
FROM TableName T1
GROUP BY T1.username,T1.Name
ORDER BY T1.username
```

See SQL SERVER example in [**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/4ecfe/1).

**MYSQL**

```
SELECT username,Name,GROUP_CONCAT(Skills) 
FROM TableName
GROUP BY username,Name
```

See MySQL example in [**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/381a7/3).

**Result:**

```
USERNAME    NAME              SKILLS
zainniazi   Zain Khan NiaZi   C,C++
```